# Hyper-V Could Not Connect to MobyLinuxVM of Docker & Docker Won't Run

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

Docker for Windows was not running. So as first step need to make MobyLinuxVM execute in Hyper-V. Hyper-V although running all virtual machines successfully but could not connect to them itself with *double errors*.

It poses error #1 on first connect thereafter error #2. What to do now, have tried many solution as mentioned below ?

**Error #1:**

[image: First Error]

**Error #2:**

[image]

**Failed Solutions**

Have tried following but failed {*Windows 10 (x64) 1703*}

1. Remove and re-install Hyper-V and 'Docker for Windows'
2. Disabled all firewalls and antivirus on the machine
3. Failed to connect 'docker for windows' with hyper-v 
   (*Stopped docker service too*)
4. Ensured that flag `hypervisorlaunchtype` is set into `Auto` in boot flags
5. Replaced `MobyLinuxVM.vhdx` and `mobylinux.iso` from another working computer in safe mode considering bugs in docker update images (*using stable version of docker for windows*)

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: After a lot of triail reinstalled and installed docker as per ```https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1043#issuecomment-348227590```

Comment: Apparently it's [by design](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1841#issuecomment-374445899). Even if you could connect to the mobylinuxvm host via the console, you wouldn't be able to login since you don't know the root pw.

Answer (score 5):

Perform the following:

```
docker run --privileged -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jongallant/ubuntu-docker-client 
docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host alpine /bin/sh
chroot /host
```

Now you are in, `ls` the file system.

If you find a better way let me know.

From: https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/ssh-into-docker-vm-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. Only way to fix it was to manually remove VMs in the directory of Hyper-V. The details are in my question [How to restore failing Docker](https://superuser.com/questions/1482582/how-to-restore-failing-docker)