# How to restore failing Docker

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

My Docker started failing after I set up an Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V. I tried reinstalling Docker but it still fails. I tried disabling Hyper-V but that resulted in forcing to repair Windows after trying to restart. Now I have two problems: Cannot run Docker and cannot disable Hyper-V.

[image]

Comment: Why downvote? It is a real pain dealing with this fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to boot into safe mode(!) and remove file of the offending Ubuntu VM from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines`. For some reason the Ubuntu VM was blocking the Docker Vm in Hyper-V. It was also impossible to kill the vmwp from task manager or from powershell. Only way to get rid of the Ubuntu VM was to find the GUID of the files and then remove the files from the specified location. Now I can run my Docker again:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker run -it debian bash
Unable to find image 'debian:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/debian
4a56a430b2ba: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:e25b64a9cf82c72080074d6b1bba7329cdd752d51574971fd37731ed164f3345
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian:latest
root@031e1475551b:/#
```